# Got a new ECM for my 2012 chevy malibu LS (flex engine) and it is showing codes for the crank shaft sensor

Tags: chevrolet, electronic-control-module, malibu

So the car will run and drive(mostly) but has codes flashing saying the "crankshaft sensor" is unlearned and keeps going into limp home mode. Does it need to be programmed again? It was programmed
prior to shipping and i installed it and everything was done right i dont understand what else needs to be done

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  If you have checked the codes, are you getting a P1336? There are procedures for doing a crankshaft sensor variation relearn.

Comment: I believe so, yes!